# Loop 3 Times and then Stop - Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, banner

Here is my code on my main frame. I need the page to only read the code from top to bottom 3 times. Even if you can think of how I can do it to just make it stop 45 seconds. Sorry, I'm brain dead and can't think anymore. Any advice?

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

import flash.utils.*;

function doStuff() {

    //startValues
    box1.back.rotationY = -90;
    box1.back.alpha=0;

    var flipSpeed:Number = .25; 
    var flipSpeedbea:Number = .04; 

    var tl:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:2});
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.front, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.back, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.back, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.front, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    var tb:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:4});

    box2.back2.rotationY = -90;
    box2.back2.alpha=0;

    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.front2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.back2, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.back2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.front2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

    var ins:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:6});

    box3.back3.rotationY = -90;
    box3.back3.alpha=0;

    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.front3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.back3, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.back3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.front3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

    var per:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:7});

    person.back_person.rotationY = -90;
    person.back_person.alpha=0;

    per.append(TweenMax.to(person.front_person, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    per.append(TweenMax.to(person.back_person, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    per.append(TweenMax.to(person.back_person, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}));

    var bea:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:7});

    be_a.bea_back.rotationY = -90;
    be_a.bea_back.alpha=0;

    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_front, flipSpeedbea, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_back, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_back, flipSpeedbea, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}));
    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_front, flipSpeedbea, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

    stop();

    setTimeout(doStuff, 15000);
}

doStuff();
```

Is it possible to set a function over doStuff to only continue functioning for 45 seconds? basically I need the function "doStuff" to play 3 times at 15 seconds each.

Comment: flash.utils.Timer:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 Thank You for responding. As it stands I'm using a timer right now that sets the movieclip to replay every 15 seconds. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around exactly what code and where I would need to put the code to get the entire movie to stop after 45 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first solution is to use a variable as a counter so that you don't need to use a Timer:

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

import flash.utils.*;

var box1:Object;
var box2:Object;
var box3:Object;
var person:Object;
var be_a:Object;

function stop() {}

var stuffCount:uint = 0;

function doStuff() {

    stuffCount++;

    //startValues
    box1.back.rotationY = -90;
    box1.back.alpha=0;

    var flipSpeed:Number = .25; 
    var flipSpeedbea:Number = .04; 

    var tl:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:2});
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.front, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.back, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.back, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.front, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    var tb:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:4});

    box2.back2.rotationY = -90;
    box2.back2.alpha=0;

    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.front2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.back2, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.back2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.front2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

    var ins:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:6});

    box3.back3.rotationY = -90;
    box3.back3.alpha=0;

    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.front3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.back3, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.back3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.front3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

    var per:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:7});

    person.back_person.rotationY = -90;
    person.back_person.alpha=0;

    per.append(TweenMax.to(person.front_person, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    per.append(TweenMax.to(person.back_person, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    per.append(TweenMax.to(person.back_person, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}));

    var bea:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:7});

    be_a.bea_back.rotationY = -90;
    be_a.bea_back.alpha=0;

    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_front, flipSpeedbea, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_back, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_back, flipSpeedbea, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}));
    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_front, flipSpeedbea, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

    stop();

    if (stuffCount < 3)
    {
        setTimeout(doStuff, 15000);
    }
}

doStuff();
```

A second solution with a `Timer` :

```
import com.greensock.;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.*;


function doStuff() {

    //startValues
    box1.back.rotationY = -90;
    box1.back.alpha=0;

    var flipSpeed:Number = .25; 
    var flipSpeedbea:Number = .04; 

    var tl:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:2});
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.front, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.back, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.back, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.front, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    var tb:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:4});

    box2.back2.rotationY = -90;
    box2.back2.alpha=0;

    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.front2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.back2, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.back2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.front2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

    var ins:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:6});

    box3.back3.rotationY = -90;
    box3.back3.alpha=0;

    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.front3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.back3, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.back3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.front3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

    var per:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:7});

    person.back_person.rotationY = -90;
    person.back_person.alpha=0;

    per.append(TweenMax.to(person.front_person, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    per.append(TweenMax.to(person.back_person, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    per.append(TweenMax.to(person.back_person, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}));

    var bea:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:7});

    be_a.bea_back.rotationY = -90;
    be_a.bea_back.alpha=0;

    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_front, flipSpeedbea, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_back, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_back, flipSpeedbea, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}));
    bea.append(TweenMax.to(be_a.bea_front, flipSpeedbea, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

    stop();
}

function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    doStuff();
}

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(15000, 3);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
myTimer.start();
doStuff();
```

Comment: You Are The Man! You and Marcela are in stiff competition to be the supreme king flash knowledge champions of all stack overflow, I just hope it doesn't end up in a actionscript battle to the death. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `doStuff` 3 times, 15 seconds apart, remove the call to `setTimeout` from inside of `doStuff`, then  do something like this:

```
var stuffTimer:Timer = new Timer(15000, 2);
stuffTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, doStuff)
doStuff(null);
stuffTimer.start();
```

You'll need to change your `doStuff` method to accept a TimerEvent:

```
function doStuff(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    [...]
}
```

Unrelated, you should move your imports OUT of the `doStuff` method and group them together with your first import statement.

Comment: back again to save the day. Thanks I grouped my import statements together, that should of been common sense on my part. Every time I try the movie now I get error "1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1" and its referring to line 75 ( http://pastebin.com/muHcntt5 )

Comment: You need to call your method with `doStuff(null);` now that it takes an argument.